# Is it possible to set the 'In-Reply-To' header on outgoing emails with AWS SES Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

I'm currently using the Boto 3 python library to send an email with Amazon SES. I'm using the send_email function, which allows me to set various headers in the outgoing email. However I do not see any way to set the 'In-Reply-To' header. Is it possible with this library?

The docs don't seem to mention any way to achieve this.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email

Comment: Yes, use the `client.send_raw_email()` and specify the `In-Reply-To` header in the `RawMessage` Data value as a newline terminated line.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a list with the field "ReplyToAddresses".

Adding this field in the example in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html

```
REPLYTO=["email1@somedomain.com","email2@otherdomain.com"]
#Provide the contents of the email.
response = client.send_email(
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
            RECIPIENT,
        ],
    },
    Message={
        'Body': {
            'Html': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': BODY_HTML,
            },
            'Text': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': BODY_TEXT,
            },
        },
        'Subject': {
            'Charset': CHARSET,
            'Data': SUBJECT,
        },
    },
    Source=SENDER,
    ReplyToAddresses=REPLYTO,
    # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
    # following line
    ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
)
```